# Change default token timeout expire to configurable in identity server 4 without using cookies

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I have a web api project that is using idenity server. Would like to make the default timeout expire to configurable (15mins) which is defaulted to 1 hour now. I see few approaches using cookies in start up. But want to set the token expiration without using cookies. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the timeout for Access tokens and Identity tokens by modifying the Client's `AccessTokenLifetime` and `IdentityTokenLifetime` properties:

```
new IdentityServer4.Models.Client {
                              .
                              .
                            ClientId = "your-application",
                            IdentityTokenLifetime = 900,
                            AccessTokenLifetime = 900
                        }
```